# How to display display numeric value as string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
def sumof
     s = 12 + 17
     puts "The sum of 12 and 17 is: " + s
end
```

When I call  **sumof**, I'm getting an error

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really one way to convert to a string, but it can be used in multiple ways. The method is called `to_s` (to string).

Way 1 (manual):

```
"Some string " + num.to_s
```

Way 2 (interpolation):

```
"Some string #{num}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to do

`"The sum is " + s.to_s` OR `"The sum is #{s}"`

the problem being that conversion to string is not implicitly done in your original example.